# Why is this path only sometimes not a git repository?

Tags: git

I have a git hook (`post-receive`) to update the documentation, run the unit-tests etc. etc., but the thing is sometimes not working.

Here are the contents of the `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
~/bubblegum_ci > /tmp/bubblegum_ci_log 2>&1 &
```

That's not hard to understand, just launch a script in the background and pipe stdout and stderr to a logfile.

Here are the contents of bubblegum_ci:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
id
cd /home/git/bubblegum
pwd
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull -v .
make genhtml doxygen
```

This one is also very simple; just cd to another repository, pull any changes, and invoke `make` to take care of the actual work. Sometimes it works just fine. Sometimes, the script gives the following output:

```
uid=1001(git) gid=1001(git) groups=1001(git),1002(www)
/home/git/bubblegum
fatal: not a git repository: '.'
make genhtml doxygen
<the output from make showing that the commits I just pushed have not been pulled>
```

That first line, `/home/git/bubblegum` obviously is the output from `pwd`, but then git fails to pull, saying it's not a git repo. I'm confused by the fact that this sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Can anyone here shed any light on the issue? Is there a race condition I haven't spotted? Otherwise I would be interested to see if there's a better way to handle this kind of thing.

Here are the permissions for /home/git/bubblegum/.git:

```
git@fancy-server:~$ ls /home/git/bubblegum -al | grep \\.git
drwxr-xr-x  8 git git   4096 Sep  2 09:58 .git
```

here is the output of `ls -l /home/git/bubblegum/.git/`:

```
$ ls -l .git
total 52
-rw-r--r--   1 git git   84 Sep  2 09:58 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 git git   23 Aug 31 15:42 HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 git git   41 Sep  2 09:58 ORIG_HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   2 git git 4096 Aug 31 15:42 branches
-rw-r--r--   1 git git  251 Aug 31 15:42 config
-rw-r--r--   1 git git   73 Aug 31 15:42 description
drwxr-xr-x   2 git git 4096 Aug 31 15:42 hooks
-rw-r--r--   1 git git 1875 Sep  2 09:52 index
drwxr-xr-x   2 git git 4096 Aug 31 15:42 info
drwxr-xr-x   3 git git 4096 Aug 31 15:42 logs
drwxr-xr-x 151 git git 4096 Sep  2 09:52 objects
-rw-r--r--   1 git git  114 Aug 31 15:42 packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x   5 git git 4096 Aug 31 15:42 refs
```

Here si the output of `mount | grep home`:

```
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: First thing I'd do is add `id` to the script to see user and group identities of the process, and check permissions of `/home/git/bubblegum/.git`. An `ls -l .git` just in case might also help if you for some reason have funny mounting stuff going on (unlikely, but who knows).

Comment: Good idea @dirkt, I have edited this information in

Comment: I do not have any other filesystems mounted in or under `/home/git/bubblegum/.git/`; I would consider this bad practise

Comment: Is `/home` NFS-mounted, or similar? And I'd still add the `ls -l .git`; as the permissions are ok, **something** must confuse `git pull`, so debugging consists of collecting information about what `git pull` in that situation actually sees that makes it complain. Also do `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull -v .`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have edited more debugging information to the post. Interestingly, with GIT_CURL_VERBOSE and GIT_TRACE both set, the output is the same when run from the script. But not from the command line. From the command line Git spews out what looks normal to me and successfully pulls.

Comment: You run `git pull .` in `/home/git/bubblegum`, meaning you pull the changes from the repo you are in? Why do you pull from `pwd` and not from another  source?

Comment: Could there be some other program/script that removes (part of) the contents of `/home/git/bubblegum` so that it in fact isn't a git repository on some runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was to do with environment variables. The clue here was the fact it worked on the command line and not in whatever environment gets spun up by whatever runs the git hook.

So I put the `env` command in the script, and noticed `GIT_DIR="."`. This explains the cryptic error message `fatal: not a git repository: '.'`. Sure enough, [setting GIT_DIR is a thing and there is a command line option to override the environment variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386291/git-git-dir-not-working-as-expected)

Thanks also to Raphael Ahrens who in the comments pointed out the incorrect period at the end of the command `git pull .`. The command to do the pull now looks like `git --git-dir="/home/git/bubblegum/.git/" pull -v` and this seems to be doing okay.